# Action doesn't exist in project still getting executed on media file execution

Tags: install4j

Abnormal behavior was i have searched for action with specific ID in my project files with ctrl+f which is not present then to be double sure i opened XML files and searched there with ctrl+f but that Action is not present anywhere.(Serached with ID)

Now if i prepare build for the same while execution that action is getting executed and i can see log for that action in /tmp/install4j log file where as the action with that ID doesn't even exist.

It is observed with latest install4j versions 8.0.8/8.0.9

Comment: Maybe it is contained in a merged project? If the action is not in the project file or any of the merged project files, it cannot be in the installer, there is no other source.

Comment: I have searched in every project file and also each XML files there is no action with that ID

Comment: You must be building with a different project file or executing an old media file then.

Comment: How can i search for that action within projects or merged projects?Like is there is any way to search that action i have checked the screen associated also found action which are called before and after that action but i am unable to find that action

Comment: Currently, there is no way to search for actions in all merged project files. You would have to search all merged project files separately. In the Installer->Screens & Actions step you can use the "Find" action to search for the ID.